# passing arrays between classes using intents

Tags: android, android-intent

i am developing a final year project where i need to retrieve details of hospitals like name ,address, location(in terms of latitude and longitude) from a server and display them on a map....connectivity has been established and i am able to retrieve the values in the from of array like address[], name[] etc..

now i need to pass these values from an activity class to map activity class...i am new to intents..can anyone please provide codes or relevant links which may be helpful in solving this problem

any help will be really appreciated....cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add data to an Intent using one of the `putExtra` routines. But serializing large amounts of data is expensive. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html#3) for alternatives.

Comment: can we use bundle to pass integer and string array...if yes then how?? i was able to pass simple variables using bundle...plzz help me out

Comment: Take a look at the `putExtra(String name, int[] value)` and `getIntArrayExtra(String name)` for an int array. There are a similar pair for String[] data.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest store that all necessary data in static list and then use that static .

```
public static List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> address = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> latitude = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> longitude = new ArrayList<String>();

name.add("your data");
address .add("your data");
latitude .add("your data");
longitude .add("your data");
```

then you can get all the data in any activity .